# Convert generic parameter to primitive datatype

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, type-conversion, anonymous-types

I have the following Sub

```
Sub InsertValueToTextbox(of t)(byval valueToInsert as t)
Dim text as String
text = valueToInsert.tostring
'Now I put the text into a textbox...
End Sub
```

My Problem is, if the value I get has decimal places I want to round it. So I tried:

```
text = Math.Round(CType(valueToInsert, Decimal), 1).ToString
```

But the compiler give me the Error that t is not convertable to decimal. `CDec` and `Convert` doesnt help here too. Can anyone tell me how I can convert an anonymous type into a primitive datatype like decimal?

Comment: thanks i changed the topic

Comment: What is this parameter used for? Is it always a numeric type or can it be any type? You could try to cast it to decimal, double etc., if the cast succeeds you can round it.

Comment: I read data from excel cells and put them into powerpoint textboxes. So every type that can be in an excel cell can be the type of t.
It can be string, ULong, Decimal, Single, Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `IConvertivble` constraint for the generic parameter which all number types and string implement:

```
Public Shared Function GetStringValueOf(Of t As {IComparable, IConvertible})(ByVal valueToInsert As t) As String
    Dim decimalValue As Decimal
    Try
        decimalValue = valueToInsert.ToDecimal(Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo)
        Return Math.Round(decimalValue, 1).ToString()
    Catch ex As  System.FormatException
        ' silently ignore this '
    End Try
    Return valueToInsert.ToString(Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo)
End Function
```

Then this works:

```
Dim result1 As String = GetStringValueOf("Test")    ' Test '
Dim result2 As String = GetStringValueOf("100,678") ' 100,7 -> comma is my decimal separator'
Dim result3 As String = GetStringValueOf(100.678)   ' 100,7 '
```

Result: 100,7

As an aside, it's not the job of that method to insert the text into the `TextBox`.

Comment: It works. Your code in the Try catch block returns me the rounded value. Now I will start to understand it! With your comment at the end you mean I should write a separate method for the job?

Comment: @ruedi: the task to assign the `TextBox.Text` is trivial. You should do it wherever you need it. But consider that this conversion method might also be useful in a context where you don't have a textbox or you don't want to assign the result to one. You don't should hard link tasks which are not related if you want to reuse your classes/methods.

Comment: Ok, I got that. Thank you very very much for helping and teaching!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Tim's method but without throwing exceptions, you could check for the actual type passed in and round only the numeric types you are interested in:

```
Function InsertValueToTextbox(Of t As IConvertible)(ByVal valueToInsert As t) As String
    Dim text As String
    Dim formatter As IFormatProvider = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture

    Select Case GetType(t)
        Case GetType(System.Decimal)
            text = Math.Round(valueToInsert.ToDecimal(formatter), 1).ToString
        Case Else
            text = valueToInsert.ToString(formatter)
    End Select

    Return text
End Function
```

Note I changed this to be a function so it returns the string value making it more re-useable

Comment: I tested this in my enviroment and it works fine as well! Thank you!